# What was the political context of the Japanese "North Ezo" explorations?

Tags: japan, exploration, edo-period

[Mamiya Rinzō](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mamiya_Rinz%C5%8D) explored [Sakhalin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sakhalin#European_and_Japanese_exploration) in 1808. This seems to have been the culmination of a series of explorations, which started in the 1770's, and in which the Japanese discovered much of the northern territories or ["North Ezo"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ezo). It seems that these trips had to do (were possibly motivated by?) with increasing Russian influence in the region. However, extant sources don't describe how these explorers (specifically Mamiya Rinzō) related to the shogunate, i.e. whether this was a specific policy of the shogunate or whether a domain had asked for permission for these activities—which is all the more surprising given [the general isolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sakoku) of the country, as well as the ban to travel outside Japan.

In general, there seem to be very few mentions relating to these Japanese explorations. [This article](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0305748806000739) seems promising but I don't have access.

A great answer would also specify whether the explorations consulted the Westerners (i.e., the Dutch) at Nagasaki to better prepare.

Comment: You can access the article [through sci-hub](https://sci-hub.tw/https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jhg.2006.05.007).